# Ansible: obtain group members taken from a variable

Tags: ansible

Usually, if I have a group called `mygroup`, to obtain all members in this group I'm using:

```
"{{ groups.mygroup }}"
```

I'm wondering how I can do the same when `mygroup` is taken from a variable.
I tried `"{{ groups.{{ variable }} }}"` but it does not work.

Any hint?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I can do:

```
group: "{{ groups.mygroup }}"
```

and then use:

```
"{{ hostvars['localhost']['group'] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

*`How can I obtain all members of the group 'mygroup' when the name of the group is taken from a variable?`*

Indirect addressing is not available in Ansible.

It is possible to [match](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings), [selectattr](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#selectattr) by a *variable* and [map](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) the list of hosts in the group. With the inventory below

```
$ cat hosts
localhost

[mygroup]
test_01
test_02
test_03
```

the play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        variable: mygroup
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ groups|
                      dict2items|
                      selectattr('key', 'match', variable)|
                      map(attribute='value')|
                      list|
                      flatten }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_hosts
```

gives

```
"my_hosts": [
    "test_01", 
    "test_02", 
    "test_03"
]
```

Comment: I'm failing to understand how your answer, answers to my question.
I have a group called mygroup, and I need to declare a variable via set_fact like: variable: "mygroup".
I need to include a yml, with a list of tasks that always uses a variable instead of the name of the group, so I need to do "{{ groups.mygroup }}" but using a variable.

Comment: You can't do "{{ groups.mygroup }}" with a variable. Read the first statement of the answer. To help you with the rest I've updated the answer with the inventory, playbook and the output.